# How to generate NS2 xgraph for throughput vs time for TCP and UDP connection?

Tags: graph, tcp, udp, simulation, ns2

Here is my code:

## Setup a FTP traffic over TCP connection

```
set ftp [new Application/FTP]
$ftp attach-agent $tcpsource
$ftp set type_ FTP
$ftp set packet_size_ 1000
$ftp set rate_ 10mb
$ftp set random_ false # setting random false means no noise
```

## Setup a CBR traffic over UDP connection

```
set cbr [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr attach-agent $udpsource
$cbr set type_ CBR
$cbr set packet_size_ 1000
$cbr set rate_ 10mb
$cbr set random_ false # setting random false means no noise
```

Answer (score 0):

"VIII. Creating Output Files for Xgraph" http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript4.html

Xgraph examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNczFLV0ZnNWdVY2s/view?usp=sharing

Example, APP-Tool with 'Instantaneous Throughput' over time .... snippet from the file `w-udp__Inst.Thr.txt`

```
--Instantaneous throughput--
        1.12134           0.536522

        2.12363            106.844

        3.12715            439.453

        4.13067            783.984

        5.13419            1128.52

        6.13771            1473.05

        7.14123            1817.58

        8.14475            2162.11

        9.14827            2506.64

         10.149            3306.11

        11.1496            6844.12

        12.1504            8871.78

        .
```

Inst_Thr-wireless-udp.png :

[image]

APP-Tool will extract information from the default trace file.tr .
Link :  https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool